# ImageButton aspect ratio is not correct

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, imagebutton

I am experimenting with placing an `ImageButton` and a TextView side by side in a *LinearLayout*, with the button big enough vertically to fit into the layout - this hopefully should fit the width. The remainder of the layout should be taken up by the text view.

At the moment, I have the following layout in my xml file:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".08"
    android:background="#004D79"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/helpButton"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/help" /> 

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="Some placeholder text"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        />

  </LinearLayout>
```

This layout is taking up 8% of the vertical space. The image for the button is 500x500.
However, I have run into some problems!
When I run with the layout above "as is", the **imagebutton** is the right height, but it takes up the entire width of the layout; there is no text view at all - so it looks like `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` is not working.
However, if I replace `android:background="@drawable/help"`  with         `android:src="@drawable/help"`, I get a small square area to the left-hand side of the layout, but there is no image on it. The textview is to the right of the "button" but it doesn't cover the rest of the layout; its wrapped so that its just big enough to encompass the placeholder text.

Will, I have to programmatically resize the button and text view in my app, eg *OnMapReady(...)*?

Edit: I've just verified that the image file is in *res/drawable/help.png* - but why it should appear with the background (wrongly sized) but no with src (correctly sized) is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

`android:adjustViewBounds` needs to be used with `android:src`, When `android:adjustViewBounds` is true ImageButton will adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable, The size may become larger.

`android:src`,`android:width`,`android:height` Determine the size of the view, `android:background` will be stretched to fill the entire view, `android:scaleType` controls how the image should be resized or moved to match the size of this ImageButton

The layout you want may have to set `android:src` and `android:scaleType` attributes

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/helpButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]